# Userform initialize messes with combo box options

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

So I have a user form and the combobox has decided it doesn't want to display the options. Here's the userform initialize code.

```
Private Sub VaporPressureUserForm_Initialize()
OptionButtonKelvin.Value = False
OptionButtonFahrenheit.Value = False
OptionButtonCelsius.Value = False
CheckBoxatm.Value = False
CheckBoxBar.Value = False
CheckBoxmmHg.Value = False
CheckBox.Valuepsia = False
ComboBox1.Clear
With ComboBox1
.AddItem "Methane"
.AddItem "Ethane"
.AddItem "n-Propane"
.AddItem "n-Butane"
.AddItem "n-Pentane"
.AddItem "n-Hexane"
.AddItem "n-Heptane"
.AddItem "n-Octane"
End With
End Sub
```

But this is not working. The combobox is named correctly and all the other buttons on the userform work but the combo box doesn't.

Also if you believe the solution is "Change the userform initialize to just have UserForm_Initialize without the beginning part", when I did this previously I would get a runtime error '424' and an object would be required so that problem would have to be fixed in addition for the userform to work.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What are the values of `ComboBox1.ColumnCount` and  `ComboBox1.ColumnWidths`?

Comment: (a) Is the code in the UserForm, or is it in a "Module"?  (b) Try placing `Me.` in front of the references to `ComboBox1`.  (c) The fact that you are getting past a line saying `CheckBox.Valuepsia = False` makes me think that you don't have `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code - please put it there (it will highlight a lot of errors which will give us a better idea of what your problem is).

Comment: It was the checkbox.valuepsia = false...I am beyond mad about how much time I spent trying to solve this problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had CheckBox.Valuepsia instead of CheckBoxpsia.value... I'm stupid